# error writing to a file : no space left on the device manjaro

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro

I am attempting to update `vscode` on my manjaro machine.

I have allocated 350GB for the home directory, but when I try to update `vscode` using add/remove software provided by manjaro,
it outputs:

```
ERROR: Failed to extract code _x64_1.tar.gz
error writing to a file : no space left on the device manjaro
```

the output of `df-h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
run             3.9G  1.5M  3.9G   1% /run
/dev/sda6        30G   28G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/loop3       44M   44M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/14549
/dev/loop1       44M   44M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/14295
/dev/loop4       65M   65M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/sublime-text/110
/dev/loop2       62M   62M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1270
/dev/loop0       62M   62M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop5       65M   65M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/sublime-text/112
tmpfs           3.9G   60M  3.8G   2% /tmp
/dev/sda8       442G   75G  345G  18% /home
/dev/sda5       229M  167M   45M  79% /boot
tmpfs           786M   76K  786M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I have dual booted manjaro and windows .

after running `sudo pacman -Sc`,

the updated result is :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
run             3.9G  1.5M  3.9G   1% /run
/dev/sda6        30G   25G  3.4G  89% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/loop3       44M   44M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/14549
/dev/loop1       44M   44M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/14295
/dev/loop4       65M   65M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/sublime-text/110
/dev/loop2       62M   62M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1270
/dev/loop0       62M   62M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop5       65M   65M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/sublime-text/112
tmpfs           3.9G   64M  3.8G   2% /tmp
/dev/sda8       442G   75G  345G  18% /home
/dev/sda5       229M  167M   45M  79% /boot
tmpfs           786M   76K  786M   1% /run/user/1000
```

the partition `/dev/sda6` has some free space but how to avoid this error once and for all.

i understood that i was downloading some applications in my root directory.

Comment: Wha's the output of `df -h`? [edit] the question adding it, use the format tool `{}` to format it as code.

Comment: i have updated my post @schrodigerscatcuriosity

Comment: I don't think you are extracting it under `/home`.

Comment: Your root file system is full: `/dev/sda6        30G   28G     0 100% /`, (the add/remove software of manjaro probably uses `/tmp` under root, not your `/home` → `/dev/sda8` partition to extract the file). The best solution IMO to avoid your system to stop working properly is to repartition again the drive, giving the root `/` (`/dev/sda6`) more space. It's not an easy task, since you would have to move/recreate your home partition, and unless you have a backup you can lose data.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity `/tmp` is almost certainly a RAMdisk, you can see it as `tmpfs` in the output of `df`. The operation is probably happening in `/var/cache` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you have allocated 350GB for your `/home` directory, you only have 30G for your root (`/`) and that is full. You need to free up some space on the `/` drive which is where this sort of operation is happening. This command will show you the largest directories in `/`:

```
sudo du -xch --max-depth 2 / | awk '$1~/G/'
```

Alternatively, you can use a graphical tool like `baobab`. The likeliest culprits will be the pacman cache under `/var/cache/pacman` and the log files in `/var/log`.

As a first step, you can run `sudo pacman -Sc` to remove no longer installed packages from the cache. From `man pacman`:

```
   -c, --clean
       Remove packages that are no longer installed from
       the cache as well as currently unused sync databases
       to free up disk space. When pacman downloads
       packages, it saves them in a cache directory. In
       addition, databases are saved for every sync DB you
       download from and are not deleted even if they are
       removed from the configuration file pacman.conf(5).
       Use one --clean switch to only remove packages that
       are no longer installed; use two to remove all files
       from the cache. In both cases, you will have a yes
       or no option to remove packages and/or unused
       downloaded databases.
```

Comment: the first step has freed some space thank you. although i need to avoid this error what's the next step. i am new to Linux excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @CharbelEid how much space was freed? As said by terdon, you can use baobab to find other possible oversized directories.

Comment: @CharbelEid the error is really simple: your disk was full so you need to free up space. I just made an educated guess for what was taking up the space, but in general the solution is just to keep an eye on your disk usage and clean up regularly.